# how to call same spring mvc controller method periodically

Tags: spring-mvc, scheduler, freemarker

I'm in a desperate need to find way to call a method annotated with @RequestMapping periodically.
The project seems to be simple. But this simplicity comes with a price.
Via poller object from Spring Integration I'm reading periodically updated data from a file. Spring Poller object accepts interval attribute which I provide by reading .properties file. Periodical data get written in a @Component which I inject into controller to fill up the model:

```
@Autowired
Results results;


@RequestMapping("/")
String exposeResults(ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("errors", results.getErrorCount());
    model.addAttribute("warnings", results.getWarningCount());
    return "results";
}
```

The model data are shown via some basic html/jsp.
I'm using FreeMarker actually as I started to follow some tutorial on Spring Boot, and it has some specific starter for FreeMarker.

The problem is I can't make that html (ftl) to auto-reload to be consistent with updated model (it gets updated indeed in console log or if I manually refresh the page).

`@Scheduled(fixedRate =..)` seems to be not applicable to MVC methods annotated with `@RequestMapping` as such methods have args and return non-void. 
And I do not consider fetching  with jquery ajax as I do not see how to feed java property as a constant needed in javascript code like `setInterval(function() {$("#displayarea").load(url); }, 10000);` ... evidently placeholders like `${polling.interval}` do not work here. Am I wrong?

I have to confess that I tried to implement `java.util.Observable-Observer' pair but failed.

I feel that it should not be that complicate and would appreciate any fresh idea.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I'm in a desperate need to find way to call a method annotated with @RequestMapping periodically

Why do you want to do that ?! It handles requests from the **client** on the **server** if you will just call it from the **server** it will not update your **client**.

> `setInterval(function() {$("#displayarea").load(url); }, 10000);`

This is exactly what you need to do `${polling.interval}` is freemarker syntax, it will retrieve the `interval` key from a `Map` named `polling` or the `interval` property of an object called `polling`, so you don't need that just `${interval}` is enough. Set it in your freemarker model, process the file that has the javascript with freemarker and you're done.

There are of course ways to set up push from the server with [WebSocket](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) for example but for what you need it will be an overkill.

Comment: Under `${polling.interval}' I meant how we reach properties in Java like
'@Value ${polling.interval} long interval' if properties-file looks like 'polling.interval = 3000'
 - the question was how to reach those properties from javascript
Sorry I did not understand your reply
Did you mean that I need to introduce some kind of FreeMarker model (Java) in my project?

Comment: You keep answering your questions in your question ;) `@Value( "${polling.interval}") long interval` will set the value from the properties file.

Comment: and you keep me wondering what was that you meant :)
Say, if I have in my class marked as @Controller a field `@Value( "${polling.interval}") long interval' - does it mean that it is accessible as ${polling.interval} from JavaScript and can be used like `setInterval(function() {$("#displayarea").load(url); }, ${polling.interval});`?

Comment: No, it means that Spring will inject the value from the properties into this field `long interval`(if everything is configured correctly). It's not going to be accessible from JavaScript. You need to do `model.addAttribute("whatever", interval); and then it will be accessible in your freemarker (ftl) template. In the template you can  do setInterval(function() {$("#displayarea").load(url); }, ${whatever}); and then freemarker will know to replace ${whatever} with 10000 or any other number that originally came from .properties file. **JavaScript will only see 10000**. @AndreyM.Stepanov

Comment: @AndreyM.Stepanov Also please see [client/server](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-71b09cc17dab5746ba91aacca3db9095) that's a very nice illustration.

Comment: But actually I'm still wondering why the syntax of addressing a model attributes is the same in FreeMarker (or say JSP) and in Javascript

Comment: @AndreyM.Stepanov They either copied from each other or coincidence.